# Column name size in derby data base

Tags: derby

In the documented limitations of **derby**, I found the item below.
What does it mean?

> If the length of the key columns in an index is larger than half the
>   page size of the index, creating an index on those key columns for the
>   table fails. For existing indexes, an insert of new rows for which the
>   key columns are larger than half of the index page size causes the
>   insert to fail.

Comment: Note that this is a limitation on the length of the **values** in the columns, not a limitation on the length of the **names** of the columns. Your question title says **Column name size**

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a defined page size for an **index** in **derby**.
Very simply, this says that your **key** for a table cannot be more than half of that page size.  Another way to look at it is that your **key** must be small enough that you can get at least two keys per index page.

Unless your keys contain long strings, or involve many columns, this should not be a problem.